# Android Layout - adding layout

Tags: android, layout

I have a issue of adding programmatically one layout into another. When I add it manualy into XML layout file it work correctly.

Why adding layout after: *example/shortcut of code*

```
LinearLayout layoutPb   = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llRowFirst);
layoutPb.addView((View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.inc_wskaznik, null));
```

doesnt look the same as I will add the inc_wskaznik layout manually into llRowFirst LinearLayout ?

---

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llRowFirst"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ff00ff" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlWskaznikRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvParametrWskaznika"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTytulWskaznika"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tvParametrWskaznika"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#fff000"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ff00ff" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlWskaznikRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvParametrWskaznika"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTytulWskaznika"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tvParametrWskaznika"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#fff000"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSecondFirst"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

   </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llThirdFirst"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

isn't the same as:

main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llRowFirst"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSecondFirst"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

   </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llThirdFirst"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

inc_wskaznik.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llWskaznikRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ff00ff" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlWskaznikRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvParametrWskaznika"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTytulWskaznika"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tvParametrWskaznika"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#fff000"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the activity:

```
LinearLayout layoutPb   = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llRowFirst);
layoutPb.addView((View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.inc_wskaznik, null));
layoutPb.addView((View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.inc_wskaznik, null));
```

Comment: Didn't get you. Elaborate please.

Comment: @Naddy - added example.

Comment: So what is the problem is there some error(show us the stacktrace) or view is not as expected?

Comment: No, there isnt any errors. View in programmitically adding isnt the same as if I copy&past it manually.

Comment: Not same means,Give some pictorial representation.

Comment: Have a look in https://github.com/BlueManLine/LayoutDiffrences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer is:

```
LinearLayout rlWskaznikRow = (LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.llWskaznikRow);
rlWskaznikRow.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,(float)1.0) );
```

Resolved in https://github.com/BlueManLine/LayoutDiffrences/commit/8e014f5c30e3d8d8fe363a8bb197bb6f7e27acf3

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine the issue is with your inflation - you should never send in null as the parent element - use the 3 parameter version of the inflater, the last parameter is a boolean as to whether to attach to root, I'd imagine here you want it true, but if it crashes simply set it false.

```
layoutPb.addView( (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.inc_wskaznik, layoutPb, true) );
```

The reason many developers put null is because it causes a crash when sending in a value - when android tries to add the child. But the problem with sending in null is that it doesn't just skip the part that causes that error but also a whole other host of useful code. By setting the third parameter to false we only skip the troublesome line.